# Can't restart docker container: OCI runtime create failed: container with id exist

Tags: linux, docker, daemon

I'm a new in a Docker, and I've tried to find solution in the google befor ask question - no result.

I decided to learn docker via practical use case - create `PostgreSQL` container into my VM instance for develop enviroment.
I've been in vacation and didn't check my server several days. Later I tried to connect to my DB, and couldnt - all of my active containers was exited with code `128`. 
I tried  to start again container with DB - `docker start django-postgres` and got error message - `Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container with id exists: 5c11e724bf52dd1cb6fd10ebda40710385e412981eb269c30071ecc8aac9e805: unknown
Error: failed to start containers: django-postgres`

I suspect that somewhere in my system docker keeps some metadata of my container which didn't removed after container was down with code `128`, but my knowledge of unix doesn't enough to determine where is it can be. Also, I'm affraid of lost my DB data connected with container.

Some techincal info:
`docker version`:

`Version:   18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:10:01 2018
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm`

`docker info`

```
Containers: 9
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 7
Images: 5
Server Version: 18.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfd04396dc68220d1cecbe686a6cc3aa5ce3667c
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-116-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 488.3MiB
ID: NDUH:OH24:4M4L:TR5O:TOIH:ARV4:LNRP:6QNE:WEYW:TMXR:7KNK:ZPDD
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Does anyone can help my understand my issue and how to fix it without lost data?

`N.B.` The second container that has been exited with code `128` was  OpenVPN. I can't restart it also, but error was differ - `cgroups: cannot found cgroup mount destination: unknown`
I found solution [here (github)](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36016):

```
Temp fix is
sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
sudo mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
```

This fix coudn't helped with Postgres container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to list all running and stopped containers using `docker ps -a`. `-a or --all` Show all containers (default shows just running).

You can find the volumes attached to your old postgres container using `docker inspect <container-id>` (Maybe pipe to less and search for volumes)

If you want to recover your data, you can attach it to a new postgres container and recover it. (If it is a root volume change target to `/`)

```
docker run --name new-postgres \
--mount source=myoldvol,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

And then you can remove the old one by using `docker rm <container-id>`.

For more information please see,

[docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/),
[docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-service-with-volumes),
[docker rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detail explanation!